# How to avoid jquery ajax to convert single quotes to escaped ones?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

First, I'm sending an entire json object, full of data. Following, is only an example of a string data that doesn't get converted properly.

starting from this string:

```
"Verticale dall'alto verso il basso, Verticale dal basso verso l'alto"
```

When sending it with jquery ajax (json), it becomes like this:

```
"Verticale dall\'alto verso il basso, Verticale dal basso verso l\'alto"
```

This is the sending code:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_url
    ,type: 'post'
    ,dataType:'JSON'
    ,data: data
```

Obviously, I don't want to get escaped single quotes. On my database I want to write "'", not "\'".

How to?

Comment: So send it as non-json?  I mean it's just a string.

Comment: Actually, why do you think you are sending it as json?

Comment: I edited the question so you can better understand. But anyway, please stick on the question meaning.

Comment: I am.  You are saying you are sending json, yet nothing about your ajax call says you are *sending* json.

Comment: Show how you're setting `data`.

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` means that the *response* is JSON, it has nothing to do with the request data.

Comment: Request data is normally URL-encoded.

Comment: Single quotes should not be a problem if your payload is properly encoded json. Are you sure that the single quote substitution takes place before sending ? You may try to represent `'` as `\u0027` (unicode code point). For json it makes no diffrence and any json parser should turn that into `'`.

Answer (score 1):

you could be smart and use a .replace all quotes to apostrophe

```
var str = "she's good";
var res = str.replace(/'/g, "’");
```

OR

You could try `var json = encodeURIComponent(string)`

Comment: Hi Jintor, the replace thing, done right and at the right place, did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Jintor, the solution was the following:

```
url: ajax_url
,type: 'post'
,dataType:'JSON'
,data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/'/g, "’"))
```

In my program, data comes to me from other sources in plain json format, then I have to add some other fields to it, and finally pass it to `$.ajax`. At that point, what I'm doing is to stringify the original object, replace all the straight quotes, than parse it to JSON again and pass it to ajax.

Probably I should also take care of double quotes, but anyway, this is my current solution.